# yii2 nginx error

Tags: ajax, yii2, nginx

На сервер отправляется ajax запрос, который обрабатывается

```
       if($request->isAjax) {

            Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;

            return ['forceClose' => true, 'forceReload' => '#crud-datatable-pjax'];
        }
```

Результатом данной операции является следущее:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что примечательно, на локальной версии не nginx все работает корректно. Отключение - подавление ошибок результата не дали. В какую сторону нужно копать ,чтобы решить проблему, насколько я понимаю, проблема как раз в сервере ,а не в самом коде. Спасибо

Comment: Надо больше кода. А так ведь видно, что 404. Не может найти ресурс какой-то.

Comment: покажите локейшены из nginx конфига